# Navigating the User to a Hidden Tab (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R Shinny application with two tabs so far. In the second tab, the user is presented with a question, and if the user selects "No" a "Next" will appear.
What I'd like to do is when the user clicks the "Next" button, I'd like the user to be navigated to a new tab (I'm going to add content at a later time).
Please keep in mind that the only way for the user to access the hidden tab is by clicking the "Next" button. When the user is in the hidden tab, there should be a "Back" button that would the user to the "Model Object" page.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('The Multi-Assumption Architecture and Testbed (MAAT) modelling system'),
  navbarPage(
    id = "maat_menu",
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
                            padding-top:10px !important; 
                            font-size: 23px;
                            padding-bottom:0 !important;
                            height: 45px;
                            }
                           .navbar {min-height:15px !important;}'))
    ),
    tabPanel("Welcome",
             mainPanel(
               style = "font-size: 20px",
               p("The MAAT framework is a", strong("tool"), "tool for comparing different", strong("models"),
                 "of processes in a simple and efficient way. It allows users to run multiple", strong("models"),
                 "with varying assumptions, parameters, and environmental conditions. With built-in", strong("sensitivity analysis"),
                 "and", strong("uncertainty quantification,"), "users can assess the impact of different process representations on 
                 model outputs. The framework also includes a", strong("parameter estimation method"), "called ", strong("Markov Chain 
                 Monte Carlo (MCMC)"), "for fine-tuning model configurations. Overall, MAAT simplifies", strong("model comparison,"),
                 " enables easy ", strong("simulation runs,"), " and provides valuable insights into model ", strong("variability"),
                 " and ", strong("parameter estimation.")), 
               hr(),
               tags$iframe(width = "560", height = "315",
                           src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/MwDqLkZ90dk",
                           frameborder = "0", allowfullscreen = TRUE)
             )
    ),
    tabPanel("Model Object",
             fluidRow(column(
               5,
               wellPanel(
                 radioButtons(
                   'model_object_buttons',
                   h4('Select a Model Object'),
                   choices = c(""),
                   width = '37%'
                 ) %>% helper(
                   icon = "question",
                   colour = "green",
                   type = "markdown",
                   title = "Model Object Description",
                   content = "model_objs_desc"
                 ),
                 shinyDirButton('directory', 'Select Directory', 'Please Select a Directory')
                 %>% helper(
                   icon = "question",
                   colour = "green",
                   type = "markdown",
                   title = "Model Object Description",
                   content = "test_md"
                 ),
               )
             )),
             fluidRow(column(
               5,
               wellPanel(
                 radioButtons(
                   'change_pars_buttons',
                   h4('Would you like to run the model using the default parameter values?'),
                   choices = c("Yes", "No"),
                   width = '100%'
                 ) %>% helper(
                   icon = "question",
                   colour = "green",
                   type = "markdown",
                   title = "Leaf Parameters Description",
                   content = "run_model_quest_exp"
                 ),
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.change_pars_buttons == 'No'",
                   actionButton('page_3', 'Next')
                 ), 
                 conditionalPanel(
                   condition = "input.change_pars_buttons == 'Yes'", 
                   actionButton('run_script', 'Run Script')
                 )
               )
             )),
             verbatimTextOutput("selected_directory"),
             verbatimTextOutput("model_object"),
             verbatimTextOutput("leaf_ex")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe_helpers(help_dir = "/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/")
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(directory_path = NULL, selected_model = NULL)
  
  # roots <- c(home = '..')
  volumes = getVolumes()()
  shinyDirChoose(input, "directory", roots = volumes, filetypes = NULL)
  
  # Get folder names within the system_models directory
  model_names <- read.csv("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/src/system_models/model_names.csv")
  
  # Update choices for selectInput0
  updateRadioButtons(session, "model_object_buttons",
                     choices = setNames(model_names$original_name, model_names$display_name))
  
  observeEvent(input$directory, {
    rv$directory_path <- parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)
    rv$directory_path <- gsub('^/Volumes/Macintosh HD', '', rv$directory_path)
    # print(rv$directory_path)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$model_object_buttons, {
    rv$selected_model <- input$model_object_buttons
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$run_script, {
    if (!is.null(rv$directory_path) && !is.null(rv$selected_model)) {
      cmd <- sprintf("/Users/fs8/Desktop/Project/MAAT/run_scripts/setup_MAAT_project.bs '%s' '%s'",
                     rv$selected_model, rv$directory_path)
      system(cmd)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$next_button, {
    # if (!is.null(rv$directory_path) && !is.null(rv$selected_model)) {
    #   
    # }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified app with your desired result. It uses shiny's tabsetPanel's "hidden" type to hide the tabs by default and then allow selection via buttons.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shiny::tabsetPanel(
        id = 'tabs', 
        # set type to hidden to hide tab selection
        type = 'hidden', 
        
        # default panel with question
        tabPanel(
            title = 'panel1', 
            h1("Page 1"), 
            h3("Question 1 - Blah blah blah?"),
            wellPanel(
                radioButtons('question1', label = "Answer:", c("Yes", "No")), 
                conditionalPanel(
                    "input.question1 == 'No'", 
                    actionButton('go_to_panel2', "Next")
                )
            )
        ), 
        
        # tab to be shown after clicking Next
        tabPanel(
            title = 'panel2',
            h2("Page 2 contents here"), 
            p("more contents here"), 
            actionButton('go_to_panel1', "Prev") # go back button
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    # button events to move tabs
    observeEvent(input$go_to_panel2, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, 'tabs', selected = "panel2")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$go_to_panel1, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, 'tabs', selected = "panel1")
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```